# Plotly chart using Javascript curve issue

Tags: javascript, html, svg, charts, plotly.js

I want to make step chart has curved line using plotly.js.
The difference between the connecting parts is felt differently depending on the size of the currently different numerical value.
The thickness of the curve path is also different.
And want to hide Xaxis and Yaxis divide lines.
I want to make the whole chart look perfect while making it the same.
Like this image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm5md.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this div -->
  <div id="plotly-div"></div>

  <body>
    <script>
      y = [0, 25, -35, -28, -10, 10, 25, 30, 35, 40, 65, 35];
      x = [0, 5, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52];
      trace = {
        line: { shape: "vh" },
        mode: "lines",
        name: "vh",
        type: "scatter",
        x: x,
        y: y,
      };
      let layout = {
        xaxis: {
          side: 'top'
        },
        showlegend: false,
        //TODO: These curves interconnect diagonal lines and horizontal lines
        shapes: [
          //Use Cubic Quadratic Curve
          {
            type: 'path',
            path: 'M 4,25 Q 4.8, 25 4.8 20',
            line: {
              color: 'black'
            },
          },
          {
            type: 'path',
            path: 'M 5.2,-30 Q 5.2, -35 5.5, -35',
            line: {
              color: 'black'
            }
          },
         

        ]
      };

      let data = [];

      for (let i = 1; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        let _x = x.slice(i - 1, i + 1);
        // trace1 for the horizontal lines
        //TODO: horizontal lines should stop at the appropriate x and y values
        
        let bigger = y[i+1] > y[i] ? true : false
       
        let _trace1 = {
          mode: 'lines',
          x: [_x[0] + 0.5, _x[1] - 1],
          y: [y[i], y[i]],
          type: 'line+markers',
          line: {
            color: 'black',
            width: 1
          }
        };
        // trace2 for the diagonal joining lines
        //TODO: diagonal lines should cover about a percentage of the distance between the  horizontal lines. Needs corrections
        let _trace2 = {
          mode: 'lines',
          x: [x[i] - 0.2, x[i] + 0.2],
          y: bigger ? [y[i], y[i + 1] + 5] : [y[i] -5 , y[i + 1] + 5],
          type: 'line',
          line: {
            color: 'green',
            width: 1
          },
        };
        diff = y[i] - y[i - 1];
        // trace3 for the vertical lines
        //TODO: vertical lines should take into consideration correct increase or decrease
        let _trace3 = {
          mode: 'lines',
          x: [x[i - 1] + 0.5, x[i - 1] + 0.5],
          y: [1, diff],
          type: 'line',
          line: {
            color: diff > 0 ? 'black' : 'red',
            width: 5
          }
        };
        layout.shapes[2*i -2] =   {
          type: 'path',
          path: `M ${x[i]-1}, ${y[i]} Q ${x[i]-1}.8, ${y[i]} ${x[i]-1}.8 ${!bigger ? y[i]-5 : y[i]+5}`,
          line: {
            color: 'black'
          },
        }
        layout.shapes[2*i -1] =   {
          type: 'path',
          path: `M ${x[i]}.2, ${bigger ? y[i+1]-5 : y[i+1]+5} Q ${x[i]}.2, ${y[i+1]} ${x[i]}.5, ${y[i+1]}`,
          line: {
            color: 'black'
          }
        },
        
        data.push(_trace1);
        data.push(_trace2);
        data.push(_trace3);
      }

      Plotly.plot("plotly-div", {
        data: data,
        layout: layout,
      });
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. I solved the issue myself.
Plotly.js had solutions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this div -->
  <div id="plotly-div"></div>

  <body>
    <script>
      y = [0, 25, -35, -28, -10, 10, 25, 30, 35, 40, 65, 35];
      x = [0, 5, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52];
      let shapes = [];
      let data = [];

      for (let i = 1; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        // trace1 for the horizontal lines
        //TODO: horizontal lines should stop at the appropriate x and y values

        let bigger = y[i] > y[i - 1] ? true : false

        let _w = (Math.abs(y[i] - y[i - 1]) / 80 + 0.3)

        let _trace1 = {
          mode: 'lines',
          x: [x[i - 1], x[i] - _w],
          y: [y[i - 1], y[i - 1]],
          type: 'line+markers',
          line: {
            color: y[i - 1] < 0 ? '#EB5757' : (y[i - 1] > 50 ? '#2F80ED' : '#000000'),
            width: 1
          }
        };
        // trace2 for the diagonal joining lines
        //TODO: diagonal lines should cover about a percentage of the distance between the  horizontal lines. Needs corrections
        let _trace2 = {
          mode: 'lines',
          x: [x[i] - _w + 0.15, x[i] - 0.15],
          y: bigger ? [y[i - 1] + 1.5, y[i] - 1.5] : [y[i - 1] - 1.5, y[i] + 1.5],
          type: 'line',
          line: {
            color: y[i] < 0 || y[i - 1] < 0 ? '#EB5757' : (y[i] > 50 || y[i - 1] > 50 ? '#2F80ED ' : '#000000'),
            width: 1
          },
        };
        var diff = y[i] - y[i - 1];
        // trace3 for the vertical lines
        //TODO: vertical lines should take into consideration correct increase or decrease
        let _trace3 = {
          mode: 'lines',
          x: [x[i], x[i]],
          y: [1, diff],
          type: 'line',
          line: {
            color: diff > 0 ? '#000000' : '#EB5757',
            width: 5
          }
        };
        data.push(_trace1, _trace2, _trace3);
        shapes.push({
          type: 'path',
          path: `M ${x[i] - _w}, ${y[i - 1]} Q ${x[i] - _w + 0.1}, ${y[i - 1]} ${x[i] - _w + 0.15} ${!bigger ? y[i - 1] - 1.5 : y[i - 1] + 1.5}`,
          line: {
            color: y[i - 1] < 0 || y[i] < 0 ? '#EB5757' : (y[i] > 50 || y[i - 1] > 50 ? '#2F80ED' : '#000000'),
            width: 1
          }
        }, {
          type: 'path',
          path: `M ${x[i] - 0.15}, ${bigger ? y[i] - 1.5 : y[i] + 1.5} Q ${x[i] - 0.1}, ${y[i]} ${x[i]}, ${y[i]}`,
          line: {
            color: y[i - 1] < 0 || y[i] < 0 ? '#EB5757' : (y[i] > 50 || y[i - 1] > 50 ? '#2F80ED' : '#000000'),
            width: 1
          }
        })
      }

      layout = {
        xaxis: {
          side: 'top',
          showgrid: false,
          autotick: false,
          ticks: 'outside',
          tick0: '',
          dtick: 5,
          tickcolor: 'red',
          showline: true,
          linecolor: '#E0E0E0',
          linewidth: 1,
          tickfont: {
            size: 0,
            color: 'red',
          },
        },
        yaxis: {
          showgrid: false,
          showline: false,
          ticks: 'outside',
          tick0: 0,
          dtick: 30,
          ticklen: 4,
          tickwidth: 2,
          tickcolor: '#BDBDBD',
          automargin: false,
          tickfont: {
            family: 'Old Standard TT, serif',
            size: 12,
            color: '#828282',
          },
          zeroline: true,
          zerolinecolor: '#828282',
          zerolinewidth: 2,

        },
        showlegend: false,
        shapes: shapes,
      }

      Plotly.plot("plotly-div", {
        data: data,
        layout: layout,
      });
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```